# Using ng-repeat to propagate a list containing another ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an angular list that propagate n objects, and inside the list items, use ng-repeat again to make a horizontal list from a property of the object which is an array

How do I accomplish that?

Here is the object I'm working with so far:

```js
    $scope.profileCompare = {

        You: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
            questionImportance: [false, true, false]
        },
        Pizza: {
            questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
            questionImportance: [false, false, true]
        },
        Greenie: {
            questionAnswer: [false, false, false, false, true, false],
            questionImportance: [true, false, false]
        }
    }
```

No real progress on how to reach the questionAnswer property with an ng-repeat to make the horizontal list inside each `<li>` of the first ng-repeat. But I'll update that as we go

Comment: can you post your HTML code?

Comment: There is none because I don't know how to do it. Unless you want to see something basic and derivative in every way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first level isn't an array, it's a dictionary of key value pairs.

You can iterate through the first level using the object syntax, `(key, value)`, and then iterate through the second tier using array syntax; something like the following:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in profileCompare">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index">{{answer}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in your case, the `value` will be an object, with 2 properties, `questionAnswer` and `questionImportance`.

The downside of using this syntax is that the order is set by the browser, and may or may not be the same as the order defined in the data set.  If you want to be able to filter, order, etc. the data, you will need to convert the objects to arrays first;  The [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) recommends using [angular-toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) for this task.

Comment: I do really want to help you get to a final solution; I wasn't trying to criticize your approach or get you to delete your newest question; I probably came on a bit strong, but I was only trying my best to encourage you to show more of the picture and pick a larger number of tags to get more exposure and better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over the first level you will need the following syntax:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in profileCompare"
```

After that, it's pretty straight forward to iterate over your array properties:

Here's the complete HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in profileCompare">
  <h2>{{key}}</h2>
  <h3>Answers</h3>
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index">
    {{answer}}
  </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Question importance</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="importance in value.questionImportance track by $index">
      {{importance}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note the track by $index** since you are iterating over booleans, which will most definitely have duplicates.

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/U20nzazg0O9qnksFIze2?p=preview